# Interpreting the neural network output in R?

Tags: r, neural-networks

I managed to create neural network of my data. But I am not so sure about the interpretation of the R output.
I used following command to create neural network:

```
> net=nnet(formula = category~iplen+date_time, size=0,skip=T,lineout=T)
# weights:  3
initial  value 136242.000000 
final  value 136242.000000 
converged
```

Then I used following command to see the output:

```
    > summary(net)
a 2-0-1 network with 3 weights
options were - skip-layer connections 
 b->o i1->o i2->o 
 0.64 -0.46  0.15
```

So from the above output Can I can conclude the following diagram of neural network?:
[image: net]

Second question is how can I know how useful this diagram is? I mean I wanted to find the category number(target variable) from the independent variables. so now how can I decide if this network really helped me to predict the category(target variable)? What is the final output or how to find that?

Can I conclude the following output from the above n-network? :

```
category= -0.46(iplen)+0.15(date_time)+0.64
```

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your interpretation looks correct.  You can check it yourself by calling `predict` on some data and comparing your calculations to `predict`.  I first did this in a spreadsheet, and then I calculated an [R neural network using metaprogramming](https://heuristically.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/nnet2sas-supports-centering-and-scaling/).

By the way, the R package `neuralnet` draws nice diagrams, but apparently it supports only regression (not classification?).

Comment: Andrew, Thanks for the reply. One more thing I wanted to discuss that as I got a equation: category=-0.46(iplen)+0.15(date_time)+0.64 from nnet output. now can I compare this with my regression equation that I can create after doing linear regression as follow: lm(category~iplen+date_time) and then linear regression equation will be something like: category=ß1(iplen)+ß2(date_time)+ß0

Comment: It is not completely clear, but classification can be achieved by setting ` linear.output=FALSE` in the `neuralnet` package. [ref](http://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-neural-network-in-r-neuralnet-package/)

Comment: Wht's the meaning of the "iter 130 value 119841.088094" and "final  value 136242.000000" lines? What are those numbers?

Comment: @skan: That is the optimization of gradient descent

Answer (score 5):

you can also use the following code for plotting nnet results

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
source_url('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fawda123/7471137/raw/466c1474d0a505ff044412703516c34f1a4684a5/nnet_plot_update.r')

#plot each model
plot.nnet(net)
```

reference : https://beckmw.wordpress.com/tag/nnet/

Comment: Hm, that's interesting, but doesn't plot very well in my case (doesn't seem to want to put weight information). Still, upvoting since having more tools is better than having less!